# Как с помощью Android Studio сконвертировать fbx файл в SFB?

Tags: android-studio, 3d, fbx

Как с помощью Android Studio сконвертировать fbx файл в SFB?

Comment: Звучит похоже на "Как с помощью фабрики сконвертироваь телефон в перфоратор". Уточните вопрос пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот подробная инструкция по данному вопросу:
https://mobikul.com/how-to-generate-sfb-model-from-obj-files-for-arcore/

> Step to convert the .obj file to .sfb
>
> 1. Install the Google Sceneform Tools plugin from plugins.
> 2. Create a sampleData folder in your project’s app folder.
> 3. Copy your 3D model source asset file (*.obj, *.fbx, or *.gltf), and all of its dependencies (*.mtl, *.bin, *.png, *.jpg, etc.) into the sampledata folder.
> 4. Right-click the 3D model (.obj) and select Import Sceneform Asset.
> 5. Change the path or name as per the requirements.
> 6. Click Finish to begin the import process.
> 7. You will find the .sfb file at the location that you mentioned in the fifth point.